# Give body 100% of the browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

**I have this:**

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

**I've tried this:**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%; //and this -> 100vh
}
```

but it didn't works.

**Here is my code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/zbjaaxe6/9/

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried giving the container `height:100%` - https://jsfiddle.net/61eguhw4/

Comment: `</span>` out of nowhere in your HTML... Probably a copy-paste error. Your question makes any sense. You're asking for `body` height 100% which is!

Comment: See CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/zbjaaxe6/18/

Comment: Your code is actually working as expected -- but your body has no content in it. Your style is saying: 'the content section should fill up as much height-space as there is content'. Add some content and the body height will grow. I **think** that what you are asking if for the content section to be fixed to the size of the window regardless of whether or not there is any content in that section. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I want the content section fill the screen height even if there is nothing in it.

Comment: The accepted answer is ok but you're relying on CSS3 - google "sticky footer" for a more widely usable solution - it's been done to death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "With vw/vh, we can size elements to be relative to the size of the 
>   viewport. The vw/vh units are interesting in that 1 unit reflects 1/100th > the width of the viewport. To make an element the full width of the 
>   viewport, for example, you'd set it to width:100vw."

-- Jonathan Snook, Sizing With CSS3's VW and VH Units

CSS:

```
[class*="col"] {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#menu{
    display:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    position:absolute;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

body {
   font: caption;

}

#content{
    min-height: 90vh;     
}

#footer{
    min-height: 5vh;     
}

#header{
    min-height: 5vh;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <!-- Small devices >= 768px Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints -->
            <div id = "header" class="col-xs-10"><span id="btnMenu" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true">TITLE</div>
            <div id="menu" class="col-xs-3 menu">
                MENU
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="col-xs-10 content">
               </span>CONTENT
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10" id = "footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem is a good candidate for ***flexbox***:

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;   // set min-height instead of height, otherwise body won't
                         // grow with content, if content is bigger than viewport
}

header {
    height: 50px;  // adjust to what you want
}

main {
    flex: 1;       // This will make the 'main' block to expand !
}

footer {
    height: 30px;  // adjust to what you want
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <main>MAIN</main>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</body>
```

**Result:**

[image]

- **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/0v4zbjcm/1/)**
- Flexbox is an IE10+ solution. [Browser support in detail](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you could use absolute positioning:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Or, you could use viewport percentages if you are cool with supporting ie9+:

```
.content {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The styles should be on the content section, not the html/body.

*EDIT*: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbjaaxe6/21/)

Comment: I want title + content + footer take 100% of the page not just the content part. I don't want scrollbar.

Comment: Check out @Michael P. Bazos 's answer below -- flexbox would be a great solution if you don't need legacy browser support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's what you want but take a look :
https://jsfiddle.net/zbjaaxe6/23/

```
.content{
position: relative;
margin: 0;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I want title + content + footer take 100% of the page not just the content part. I don't want scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

I solved your issue using flexbox property.

```
.container, 
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
#title, 
#footer {
    flex: none;
}
#content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fL51hazq/) the solution.